# How to use bpy.ops.object.transfer_mode() API?

Tags: python, add-on, shortcut, operator

I'm a beginner :(
The purpose of these codes is to make the shortcut "alt+q" have different Operators under different "C.object.types",
but "bpy.ops.object.transfer_mode" never works and I don't know how to use this strange api.

```
class PIE_Bottom_Q_alt(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "pie.q_alt_key"
    bl_label = __name__.split('.')[-1]
    bl_options = {"REGISTER"}

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return True

    def execute(self, context):
        mode = context.object.mode
        if mode == 'SCULPT':
            #------ This operator not working ------#
            bpy.ops.object.transfer_mode()
        elif mode == 'OBJECT' or 'EDIT':
            bpy.ops.view3d.localview(frame_selected=False)
        return {"FINISHED"}


classes = [
    PIE_Bottom_Q_alt,
]

addon_keymaps = []


def register_keymaps():
    addon = bpy.context.window_manager.keyconfigs.addon

    km = addon.keymaps.new(name="3D View", space_type="VIEW_3D")
    kmi = km.keymap_items.new(
        PIE_Bottom_Q_alt.bl_idname,  'Q', 'CLICK', alt=True)


def unregister_keymaps():
    wm = bpy.context.window_manager
    for km in addon_keymaps:
        for kmi in km.keymap_items:
            km.keymap_items.remove(kmi)
        # wm.keyconfigs.addon.keymaps.remove(km)
    addon_keymaps.clear()


def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
    register_keymaps()


def unregister():
    unregister_keymaps()
    for cls in reversed(classes):
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
```

Comment: Can you post the error codes in question? What exactly do you mean it "doesn't work"? Is the pie menu not popping up at all? Is the button being clicked doing nothing? Is there a big error traceback in the console?